# Autogenerated class from web service

Tags: wpf, wcf, web-services

I'm working with a .net webservice which has some class in it. Next I generated proxy class that contains this class. But in webservices I defined for some fields validation rules like Regular expression or error messages etc.

```
[DataMember]
[Required(ErrorMessage = ErrorMessages.DefaultRequiredErrorMessage)]
[Display(Order = 2, Name = "Email")]
[RegularExpression(@"^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$",
    ErrorMessage = "Email is not correct.")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

i would like to have this validation rules in generated class. Instead I have only class:

```
 [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string Email {
        get {
            return this.EmailField;
        }
        set {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.EmailField, value) != true)) {
                this.EmailField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Email");
            }
        }
    }
```

Is it possible? How can I get this validation rules in the class?

Answer (score 0):

That is only one of the downsides with auto generated proxies.

If you can, reference the DLL/project where entity/dto is defined and then use WCF to create  proxies.

[This](http://blog.bodurov.com/Create-a-WCF-Client-for-ASMX-Web-Service-Without-Using-Web-Proxy/) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

For your case I share the same source file between two projects,
( I mean the same namespace and etc..)

serilaization and deserialization work fine. 
And I may use the same custom logic in two places.